# How to get Scroll offset in RadDataBoundListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, telerik, rad-controls

We are trying to find vertical offset when user try to scroll the RadDataBoundListbox in windows phone 8 silverlight. For e.g : the position at which Listbox scrolled.

So far we are trying registering with ScrollStateChanged event but this event only returns Scrolling states like TopStretch, Scrolling, NotScrolling etc.

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox x:Name="MessagesList" IsAsyncBalanceEnabled="True" Style="{StaticResource RadDataBoundListBoxStyle1}">
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ScrollStateChanged">
                            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ScrollChangedCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>                           
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>                        
                </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
```

We couldn't find any Event / approach to solve this problem.

Any idea regarding solving this problem might be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `ScrollViewer` from the `RadDataBoundListBox` and access it directly. There is no event for when the `ScrollViewer` scrolls like in WP81 and UWP so you need to create a binding to the `VerticalOffset` property and observe its changes.

Comment: Any clue regarding, how to get ScrollViewer from the RadDataBoundListBox ?

Comment: take a look ak VisualTreeHelper or the TemplatedVisualTreeExtensions.GetFirstLogicalChildByType method from teh Coding4Fun toolkit